# matching date in circular range

Tags: sql, date, range, modulus

I am trying to figure out if a certain event happened within a few weeks of someone's birthday. The year doesn't matter; only the month and day.

For example, I want to know if the event (January 5) is within 4 weeks of the birthday (Dec 18).

In SQL, I have 
`SELECT ..... where abs(week(event)-week(birthday))<5`

This works well if both the event and the birthday are between weeks 4 and 48 in the year.

How can I set up the query so that it works for the edge months?

Comment: what do you mean by edge months?

Comment: what I meant was that in january, the week is going to be 1-4, while in december, the week will be 48 or more. So the problem is that if you compare Dec. 18 and January 5, they will be in weeks 50 and 2, respectively. If you do `abs(50-2)` you get 48, which makes it seem that the two dates are more than 3 weeks apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server I'd use `DATEDIFF` and `%` (modulo).

```
SELECT
...
WHERE
(ABS(DATEDIFF(day, @date1, @date2)) % 365) < 4*7
OR
(ABS(DATEDIFF(day, @date1, @date2)) % 365) > 365 - 4*7
```

To make calculations correct even when `@date1` and `@date2` are in different years with leap years in between, I'd move both dates into the same year. It depends on the DBMS you use, how to change the year component of the date, but once both dates are in the same year modulo is not needed:

```
SELECT
...
WHERE
ABS(DATEDIFF(day, @date1, @date2)) < 4*7
OR
ABS(DATEDIFF(day, @date1, @date2)) > 365 - 4*7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`DATEDIFF`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(week,'2014-06-05','2015-08-05') AS DiffDateInWeeks
```

Note that this function might have a different name (or parameters) depending on the DBMS.
For MySQL for example the [`DATEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function has no 'date part' parameter, so you could do something like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3960485/1771479):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2014-06-05','2015-08-05')/7.0 AS DiffDateInWeeks
```